# Importing PKCS#8 encrypted key to RSACng?

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, cng

If I have encrypted RSA key in PKCS#8, can I somehow import it to `RSACng` as `CngKeyBlobFormat.Pkcs8PrivateBlob`? Or does this `CngKeyBlobFormat.Pkcs8PrivateBlob` just shows the `CngKey` that during import the key must be decoded from DER to get key parameters and then they are imported into `RSACng`, thus the answer is no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CNG understands how to decrypt encrypted PKCS#8, but you need to give it a password.  Since .NET doesn't ask you for the password (and it gets passed via a manner other than the properties) there isn't a good way to do it.

Your options are pretty much:

- P/Invoke so you can specify the NCRYPTBUFFER_PKCS_SECRET value.
- Change your process so that you have an unencrypted PKCS#8.
- Change your process so that you have a PFX/PKCS#12 instead of an encrypted PKCS#8 (and then change to reading it via X509Certificate2).
- Wait for a future version of .NET Core, which will have the ability to load a PKCS#8, encrypted PKCS#8, and some other formats, directly into the RSA/DSA/ECDsa/ECDiffieHellman objects (feature is currently in the master branch).
- Find a library which can decrypt it for you.  Bouncy Castle can probably do it.

See also: [Digital signature in c# without using BouncyCastle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48905438/6535399)