# Create X509Certificate2 from Cert and Key, without making a PFX file

Tags: c#, ssl, certificate, x509certificate2

In the past I have been making secure TcpListener by exporting a PFX certificate with a password, but would like to know if this step could be skipped.

I'm not using commercial SSL certificates, and have a Root CA, that I use to issue server certificates. These server certificates require additional steps when hosting a TcpListener in C# (I guess because the CSR wasn't used)... but what if I do have the Private Key, and the Certificate that OpenSSL generates/uses.

```
sslCertificate = new X509Certificate2("myExportedCert.pfx", "1234");
```

So this is great, however I have to issue an openssl command to make a pfx file from the Certificate and the Private Key, then make up some password. Then include this password in my code.

I was wondering if this step was quite necessary. Is there a way to make up a X509Certificate2 from the Cert, and then apply the Private Key. The constructor arguments allow the Cert only part, but encrypting fails then because there is no private key.

Also, I don't want to rely on OpenSSL or IIS to export the pfx.... seems clumsy.

Ideally i would like:

```
sslCertificate = new X509Certificate2("myCert.crt");
sslCertificate.ApplyPrivateKey(keyBytes) // <= or "private.key" or whatever

sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(sslCertificate, false, SslProtocols.Default, false);
```

Comment: I'm using .net 4, if it makes any difference

Comment: Hi Conrad, I know this is old, I'm stuck with exact same problem, can we have a chat and sort this out. Thank you

Comment: @Clint, I left my solution with the OpenSSL call in place. It works without fail, and though is an external application to reference (and less clean or pure code), it works!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There are a couple of different things you're asking for, with different levels of ease.

## Attaching a private key to a certificate

Starting in .NET Framework 4.7.2 or .NET Core 2.0 you can combine a cert and a key.  It doesn't modify the certificate object, but rather produces a new cert object which knows about the key.

```
using (X509Certificate2 pubOnly = new X509Certificate2("myCert.crt"))
using (X509Certificate2 pubPrivEphemeral = pubOnly.CopyWithPrivateKey(privateKey))
{
    // Export as PFX and re-import if you want "normal PFX private key lifetime"
    // (this step is currently required for SslStream, but not for most other things
    // using certificates)
    return new X509Certificate2(pubPrivEphemeral.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx));
}
```

on .NET Framework (but not .NET Core) if your private key is `RSACryptoServiceProvider` or `DSACryptoServiceProvider` you can use `cert.PrivateKey = key`, but that has complex side-effects and is discouraged.

## Loading the private key

This one is harder, unless you've already solved it.

For the most part the answer for this is in [Digital signature in c# without using BouncyCastle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48905438/6535399), but if you can move to .NET Core 3.0 things get a lot easier.

### PKCS#8 PrivateKeyInfo

Starting in .NET Core 3.0 you can do this relatively simply:

```
using (RSA rsa = RSA.Create())
{
    rsa.ImportPkcs8PrivateKey(binaryEncoding, out _);
    // do stuff with the key now
}
```

(of course, if you had a PEM you need to "de-PEM" it, by extracting the contents between the BEGIN and END delimiters and running it through `Convert.FromBase64String` in order to get `binaryEncoding`).

### PKCS#8 EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo

Starting in .NET Core 3.0 you can do this relatively simply:

```
using (RSA rsa = RSA.Create())
{
    rsa.ImportEncryptedPkcs8PrivateKey(password, binaryEncoding, out _);
    // do stuff with the key now
}
```

(as above, you need to "de-PEM" it first, if it was PEM).

### PKCS#1 RSAPrivateKey

Starting in .NET Core 3.0 you can do this relatively simply:

```
using (RSA rsa = RSA.Create())
{
    rsa.ImportRSAPrivateKey(binaryEncoding, out _);
    // do stuff with the key now
}
```

(same "de-PEM" if PEM).

Comment: Thanks, @bartonjs, If I got to .NET Core, ill use this - for now, I'l just use a Process() to get OpenSSL to make the .pfx file, since I have the .crt and .key files at hand. (Does seem odd tho that this is not available in .NET4 - seems like quite a rudimentary requirement to be able to host a secure TCP service with a CA, Certificate and private key)

Comment: I am not too familiar with security. What is the process required to create a `privateKey` from a `.key` file?

Comment: Is there some reason that I'm not seeing as to why you don't just use `X509Certificate2.CreateFromPem`? You make a statement about de-PEMing everything, but the class supports PEM-encoded certs and keys. There's also `RSA.ImportFromPem` and `RSA.ImportFromEncryptedPem` for importing keys directly. I only ask all of this because I spent an inordinate amount of time building my own de-PEMing logic today after reading your answer, and then I found the docs for those methods.

Comment: @b4ux1t3 Just the linear nature of time.  This answer was written before any of those methods were created.

Comment: Ah, you're right, it looks like these were added in .NET 5! My mistake.

Answer (score -5):

In the end i did this, and it works fine:

```
...
if (!File.Exists(pfx)) {
    // Generate PFX
    string arguments = "openssl pkcs12 -export -in " + certPath + "" + certFile + ".crt -inkey " + certPath + "" + certFile + ".key -out " + certPath + "" + certFile + ".pfx -passout pass:" + pfxPassword;
    ProcessStartInfo opensslPsi = new ProcessStartInfo("sudo", arguments);
    opensslPsi.UseShellExecute = false;
    opensslPsi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    using (Process p = Process.Start(opensslPsi)) {
        p.WaitForExit();
    }
    // Set Permission
    ProcessStartInfo chmodPsi = new ProcessStartInfo("sudo", "chmod 644 " + certPath + "" + certFile + ".pfx");
    chmodPsi.UseShellExecute = false;
    chmodPsi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    using (Process p = Process.Start(chmodPsi)) {
        p.WaitForExit();
    }
}
sslCertificate = new X509Certificate2(pfx, pfxPassword);
...
```

Comment: This does precisely what the question asks to avoid.