# Generate access token to authenticate Azure Active directory App

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-authentication

I am using Azure Active Directory App to authenticate my rest endpoint deployed on Azure.
I was using pfx cert type and below code to generate access token so that my endpoint can be accessed through that access token.

```
        var authority = string.Format(authorityUri, credentialConfigOptions.TenantId);
        var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
        X509Certificate2 certificate = default;using (var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser, OpenFlags.ReadOnly))
        {
            var certificateCollection = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, credentialConfigOptions.CertificateName, false);
            if (certificateCollection.Count > 0)
            {
                certificate = certificateCollection[0];
            }
        };
        
        var clientAssertionCertificate = new ClientAssertionCertificate(credentialConfigOptions.AppId, certificate);
        AuthenticationResult token = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(appId, clientAssertionCertificate);
        return token?.AccessToken;
```

Now I have to use PEM cert type instead of pfx cert type so I am  getting issues while converting PEM format to X509Certificate2.
How can I generate access token with PEM certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Net 5.0, we can directly create `X509Certificate2` with a cert and key with method `X509Certificate2.CreateFromPemFile(<certpath>,<keypath>)`. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.createfrompemfile?view=net-5.0).

If you use other versions, we can create an `X509Certificate2` with cert file then import private key with method `CopyWithPrivateKey`. At last we create Certificate with code
`new X509Certificate2(pubKey.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx))`. For more details, please refer  to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55456807/create-x509certificate2-from-cert-and-key-without-making-a-pfx-file).

Comment: I am using .net core 3.1 where X509Certificate2.CreateFromPemFile(<certpath>,<keypath>) is not supported.

Comment: @AmitAgrawal If so, please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55456807/create-x509certificate2-from-cert-and-key-without-making-a-pfx-file